# graph theory δ(G) + δ(complement G) <= n - 1

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

Hi I am new to graph theory and being terrible with proofs I am looking for some hints to prove this:

Prove that if G is a graph of order n, then δ(G) + δ(complement of G) ≤ n − 1.

I know that degG(v) = (n - 1) - degComplementG(v)
and that δ(G) ≤ 2m/n ≤ Δ(G) where m is the size of G and  n is the order.
But I am not sure what to do next.

I also need to prove that for a graph G of order n, that δ(G) + δ(complementG) = n − 1 if and only if G is regular but I feel if I get the first proof ill be able to prove this as well.

Comment: $\delta(G) + \delta(\bar G) = \delta(G) + (n - 1 - \Delta(G))$

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary vertex $v$, then $|\delta_G(v)|+|\delta_{\bar{G}}(v)|=|V(G)|-1$. By definition, $\delta(G)\leq|\delta_G(v)|$ for all $v\in V(G)$, hence, $\delta(G)+\delta(\bar{G})\leq n-1$, where $n=|V(G)|$.